# Scrape webpage for all strings containing a number of substrings (i.e. key words)

Tags: python, lambda, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to this and keep hitting walls with what I'm trying to achieve so thought I would reach out to the community for help.  I would like to be able to extract a full string of text from a webpage if one of my key words appears as a substring within it.  I've been using beautiful soup but am open to trying something else.

The website I'm using for my example is www.meridianenergy.co.nz.  The key words I'm interested in are 'sustainable', 'renewable' and 'electric cars'.  Essentially I want to extract every string that's visible on the home page in which one or more of those terms appears in.

So far I've been able to do it for one term at a time using the code below but I'd like to be able to look for all the key words at once if possible (because I may need to add lots more key words over time).  Thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.meridianenergy.co.nz')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: 'renewable' in text)
print(results)
```

Comment: you can add all the keywords into a list, and then iterate over the list and check if there is a match with the soup object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all your keywords in a list format. And then iterate over it while traversing the soup object.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.meridianenergy.co.nz')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
keywords_to_find = ['sustainable', 'renewable', 'electric cars']
results = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: text and any (x in text for x in keywords_to_find))
print(results)
```

Result

> ['100% renewable energy generation', 'All the energy we generate comes
>   from 100% renewable sources – wind, water and sun. We’re New Zealand’s
>   largest generator, making power through our wind farms, hydro stations
>   and solar arrays. That’s where the magic happens. We believe renewable
>   energy is the only way forward for the future of our planet.',
>   'Turbine™ - brewed with certified renewable energy', "We're pretty
>   proud of the team at Garage Project. Last year, they brewed a beer
>   with 100% certified renewable energy from our Brooklyn Turbine. That's
>   the bit we helped out with - and we're excited to be working on a
>   certified renewable energy product for other businesses.", 'You can
>   spot New Zealand’s first certified renewable energy mark on a bottle
>   of Garage Project’s Turbine™\xa0beer. Cheers to that.', ' is a New
>   Zealand power company that generates electricity through 100%
>   renewable sources – wind, water and sun. We believe it’s the only way
>   forward for people and the planet. ']

Hope this helps.

Comment: by the way, @l-s, i just noticed the webpage has text for `electric-car` and not `electric-cars`. So, if you want text for the same, then amend the list variable `keywords_to_find` with the same.